# Manually add a product to cart using ajax in opencart

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, opencart

I need to add a product to the cart once the user click a button by using my own function.

The button code:

```
 <input type="button" value="Add to cart" onclick="addItemsToCart(83); " class="button btn-success"  id="addToCartButton1"/>

 <input type="button" value="Add to cart" onclick="addItemsToCart(84); " class="button btn-success"  id="addToCartButton2"/>
```

**addItemsToCartFunction**:

```
function addItemsToCart(option_value_id){

        $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/add',
        type: 'post',
        data: 'product_id=' + 92+ '&quantity=' + 1, //need to change this
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json) {
            $('.success, .warning, .attention, .information, .error').remove();

            if (json['redirect']) {
                location = json['redirect'];
            }

            if (json['success']) {
                $('#notification').html('<div class="success" style="display: none;">' + json['success'] + '<img src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/close.png" alt="" class="close" /></div>');

                $('.success').fadeIn('slow');

                $('#cart-total').html(json['total']);

                $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow'); 
            }   
        }
    });

    }
```

This is working properly.

But This product has a option called 'custom'.

option details according to the database:

```
option id: 17
option values ids 83 and 84.
```

I have passed the option value as a parameter to the function addItemsToCart.

Now I need to pass that option and value to the data section. That means I need to change this line.

```
data: 'product_id=' + 92+ '&quantity=' + 1,
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Since you take the parameter option_value_id, I think you want this:

```
data: {product_id: option_value_id, quantity: 1},
```

Check out [jQuery Docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to learn more.

Comment: Actually this is not I need. I need to pass the product option Id and value to this object. Thank you for the answer

Comment: I don't completely understand. You call the jQuery function with an integer as the parameter (option_value_id) that is 83 and 84 in your examples above. For what do you need it afterwards?